# How to use map function to display json having spaces on key to component on React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm Trying to consume an API of stock market, So I make an API call when the form is submit and received this JSON Bellow and store his value on Hook.

```
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "IBM",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-12-04",
        "4. Output Size": "Compact",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2020-12-04": {
            "1. open": "123.9700",
            "2. high": "127.3800",
            "3. low": "123.6400",
            "4. close": "127.2000",
            "5. volume": "5522760"
        },
        "2020-12-03": {
            "1. open": "124.1600",
            "2. high": "124.8600",
            "3. low": "123.2900",
            "4. close": "123.6100",
            "5. volume": "4548161"
        }
}
```

So I create two simple components: StockList and StockItem, StockList is used to render all StockItem, I can't access the value of JSON in StockItem because I dont know how to display this data having spaces on keys. Usually the jsons is like this:

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    }
```

It's easy to display using map like this:

```
users.map((user) => {
   return(
     <p>{user.name}</p>
     <p>{user.username}</p>
   )
});
```

When I tried to use map to resolve this question I got undefined propertie.

Comment: user['key'] => example : user['first name'], try this and let me know

Comment: For example,  let a = {"first name": 'dileep'}; a['first name']

Comment: Let me know if it helped you or not

Answer (score 1):

To access the data which having spaces on keys.

```
user['key'] => 

example : user['first name']
```

```js
let a = {"first name": 'dileep'}; 
console.log(a['first name'])
```